# pg_dump ERROR: malformed record literal

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table called "name" in a database also called "name". I have had no issues backing up other databases on the server. But for this database I am getting the following error

```
root@latitude:~/pg_backup_lenovo# pg_dump -h 192.168.1.201 -U superusername name > name.dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  malformed record literal: "bigint"
LINE 1: SELECT 'bigint'::name AS sequence_type, start_value, increme...
               ^
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT 'bigint'::name AS sequence_type, start_value, increment_by, max_value, min_value, cache_value, is_cycled FROM name_id_seq
```

My schema

```
CREATE TABLE public.name
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('name_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    sex text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT name_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I'm not sure what's happening here. Could this be a possible bug?

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. We should be using `pg_catalog.name` in the cast. Please report a bug to the pgsql-bugs mailing list.

Comment: from `sequence_type` I assume you use recent 10?.. maybe tag it?..

Answer (score 3):

`name` is a built-in type located in the `pg_catalog` namespace.

When creating a table with that name in the `public` schema, that creates
another type also named `name` in the `public` schema, because
each table is also a composite type. You may check that with `select * from pg_catalog.pg_type where typname='name'`

**Normally** when casting something to `name`, as does the query that
fails (`SELECT 'bigint'::name AS sequence_type...`), it's the
type in `pg_catalog` that gets picked up, because `pg_catalog` goes implicitly before `public`
in the `search_path`, as mentioned in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html):

> In addition to public and user-created schemas, each database
>   contains a pg_catalog schema, which contains the system tables and all
>   the built-in data types, functions, and operators. pg_catalog is
>   always effectively part of the search path. If it is not named
>   explicitly in the path then it is implicitly searched before searching
>   the path's schemas. This ensures that built-in names will always be
>   findable. However, **you can explicitly place pg_catalog at the end of
>   your search path if you prefer to have user-defined names override
>   built-in names**.

The error message obtained with `'bigint'::name` means
that postgres resolves the cast with the type corresponding
to your table in the `public` schema, whereas clearly `pg_dump`
expects that it would find the built-in `name` type instead.

So it looks like you're in the case emphasized in the paragraph quoted above, in a way that conflicts with built-in types, at least for `pg_dump`.

To test that theory, check the `search_path` of the
user running `pg_dump` and try to dump again after resetting it to a innocuous value, such as with:

`ALTER USER user_running_pg_dump SET search_path TO public;`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think the simplest solution would be to change my database/table name from name to something else